# Enter shared location through a command line

Tags: windows, command-line, shared

I need to enter shared location (on differend computer) through a command line to run git commands there. How to do that? Something like this:

```
cd \\OTHERCOMPUTERNAME\Shared_folder
```

won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pushd \\OTHERCOMPUTERNAME\Shared_folder
```

Now you can use `cd` and `dir` as normal to navigate around. When finished, use this command:

```
popd letter
```

Replace `letter` with the drive name you can see. Usually, it will be `Z:\` or `Y:\`. If your path is something like `Z:\`, then use this command:

```
popd Z
```